# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "type"

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to connect hibernate with PostgreSQL(10.2) using the *org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect* and by default hibernate(5) is adding TYPE=MYISAM when creating a table in PostgreSQL. Then it was throwing this error **Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "type"** in Eclipse. I know that TYPE is changed to ENGINE in MYSQL present versions but I want to use PostgreSQL. Any possible ways of changing TYPE=MYISAM in hibernate classes or any other solutions? Please help me to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, unless you have some MySQL scripts being executed by your app, the TYPE=MYISAM shouldn't happen at all when using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect. Are you sure your tables are being created by Hibernate and not other means?

Comment: Add database connectivity properties and query to your post

Comment: Thank you @SimonBerthiaume and there are no MySQL scripts manually added. I provided the entity and columns to add hibernate automatically to the PostgreSQL and when I tried running this using MYSQL, I fixed the error which came up that TYPE is deprecated after MySQL 4.0 so that I downgraded the MYSQL version then it runs well. Now I want to go with PostgreSQL(10.2) where Hibernate automatically creates the table and adding TYPE=MYISAM and even tried with different dialects of postgresql. I am using postgresql.42.2.1 jar

Comment: Thank you, @AjitSoman and database connectivity parameters are good because I tried connecting with MYSQL and everything worked well and I am using postgresql.42.2.1 jar here with postgresql.

Comment: Could you provide the entity code, I've user Hibernate with Postgres in the past and it didn't try to add that TYPE=MYISAM thing so it's either something in your class or in your persistence context (XML) declaration that is causing that.

Comment: Hey, @SimonBerthiaume thank you and I had fixed that error. In servlet XML file it was referring to MySQL driver in the code. I just removed it and re-configured with hibernate details. Now it runs well.                                       *Thank you*